# shortest code to find the field value of any node in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

I have been using this code in Drupal 7 to get value of a node's field:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$rate = $node->field_rate[und][0][value];
```

How to get `$rate` value without using this long array syntax?

After research i get

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_rate')
$rate = $field[0]['value'];
```

But it is still long if i need to get `n` number of fields.

Comment: `field_get_items` is a best way to get value because it manage for you language. If you need to get values for several field , you have to make a custom function use `field_get_items` in a loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`field_get_items` is a best way to get value because it manage for you language. Otherwise you can make a sql query if you want more field. Also you can create a custom function like this :

```
    /**
     * @param        $entity_type
     * @param        $entity
     * @param  array $field_names // field_names
     * @param  null  $langcode
     * @return array
     */
 function multi_field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $field_names = array(), $langcode = NULL){
  $field_values = array();
  foreach ($field_names as $field_name){
    $data =  field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $langcode);
    if(is_array($data) && count($data) > 1){
      foreach ($data as $several_values) {
        $field_values[ $field_name ][] = current($several_values);
      }
    }else if(is_array($data) && count($data) == 1){
      $field_values[ $field_name ] = current(current($data));
    } else {
      $field_values[ $field_name ] = null;
    }
  }
  return $field_values;
}
```

Example :

```
$field = multi_field_get_items('node', $node, array('field_rate'));

var_dump($field); // array('field_rate' => 'value of field rate');
```

If is a collection, it will return  :

```
array('field_rate' => array('value of field rate 1', 'value of field_rate 2'));
```